Getting the current user using cognito and javascript
I am using javascript, lambda and cognito for a web application. I need the get the current user information after sign in on the other pages. How can access the current logged in user?
var user = localStorage.getItem("user"); Does this work?
Or should I use sth like this?
    var poolData = {
     UserPoolId : 'us-east-1_xxxxxxxxxxx', // Your user pool id here
     ClientId : '7q1q1q1q1q1q1q1q1q1q1q1q1q1' // Your client id here
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(poolData);
    var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();```

